# length wont work after clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareksmakosz/2U7W6/2/), where I would like to:

- after clicking on the `.original` div, duplicate it, where the duplicates will have a class `.black`, instead of `.original`.
- remove the .original div if the .container contains more than one divs with the class of `.black`

So far I got the former working, but the latter doesn't seem to work.
Is it because the content is created with jQuery?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="original"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.original {
    display: block;
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
}
.black {
    display: block;
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: black;
}
```

```js
$('.container').on('click', '.original', function () {
    $(this).clone(true).addClass('black').insertAfter($(this)).removeClass('original');
});
$('.container').each(function () {
    console.log($('.black').length);
    if ($('.black').length > 4) {
        $('.original').fadeOut(600);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just corrected, thanks. But it's not the solution.

Comment: you need to move the check to inside the click handler otherwise it will only run once in the begining. http://jsfiddle.net/2U7W6/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2U7W6/5/ try this

Comment: Why was this closed? The problem is right there, as Vic and Neel stated

Comment: I think this question should not be closed

Comment: Thank you for solving it, @Vic.

Comment: Admittedly this question should have the code posted within it, not just a link to a fiddle, but closing seems a little harsh.

Comment: @Vic if you put it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks to everyone, though.

Answer (score 2):

you need to move the check to inside the click handler otherwise it will only run once in the begining.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').on('click', '.original', function () {
        $(this).clone(true).addClass('black').insertAfter($(this)).removeClass('original');
        var itemsNumber = $('.black').length;
        $('.container').each(function () {
            if (itemsNumber > 4) {
                $('.original').fadeOut(600);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/2U7W6/4](http://jsfiddle.net/2U7W6/4)

Answer (score 1):

The code to fade out is being called only once (in ready function). You need to move the code inside the click function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.container').on('click', '.original', function () {
    $(this).clone(true).addClass('black').insertAfter($(this)).removeClass('original');

    var itemsNumber = $('.black').length;
    $('.container').each(function () {
        if (itemsNumber > 4) {
            $('.original').fadeOut(600);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you check and set value for number of boxes, so its inilized just first time, and the`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').on('click', '.original', function () {
        $(this).clone(true).addClass('black').insertAfter($(this)).removeClass('original');
    });
    $(".original").click(function(){
    var itemsNumber = $('.black').length;
    $('.container').each(function () {
        if (itemsNumber > 4) {
            $('.original').fadeOut(600);
        }
    });
    });
});`